# How can I generate Cassandra data model from a MySQL schema?

Tags: mysql, schema, cassandra

Is there a tool for generating a Cassandra model from a MySQL database?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to come up with that on your own. Your question certainly begs the bigger question, "what kind of research have you done already?" Additionally, what is the motivation for moving away from an RDBMS to a NoSQL solution (not that it's always bad).

Answer (score 12):

The whole point of NoSQL is that it doesn't use the same type of datastructures as an SQL database.  It requires a whole different way of thinking and approach with your app, so there isn't something to handily copy the schema over because it is going to be unique to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could at least try [CQL](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/dml/using_cql). It attempts to imitate SQL, with many limitations though, as it has to fit with Cassandra characteristics as set by JamesRyan

Comment: While CQL bears some similarities to SQL, it won't help the OP build his data model from MySQL.